# RDLC In Asp.net And Adding table dynamically

Tags: dynamic, datatables, report, rdlc

I am working on RDLC report in asp.net, Can I add table dynamically. I also have a nested table structure and want to implement it

I tried different approaches like try to add a table at controller end but its not working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.